# sidesubfloat: how to change the space between the label and float?

Tags: sidesubfloat

In the example below, how can I change (say, increase) the spacing between the labels and the floats? I tried tweaking the capbesidesep parameter, but it seems to have no effect.
Thanks and regards, Jorge.

Example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{floatrow}

\newlength\mysep \setlength\mysep{1cm}
\DeclareFloatSeparators{mysep}{\hskip\mysep}
\floatsetup[figure]{style=plain,subcapbesideposition=top,capbesidesep=mysep}


\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\sidesubfloat[]{\includegraphics[scale=0.25]{example-image-a}}
\\
\vspace{1cm}
\sidesubfloat[]{\includegraphics[scale=0.25]{example-image-b}}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Output:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could modify `\labelsep` to change the space between the label and the image:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{floatrow}

\floatsetup[figure]{style=plain,subcapbesideposition=top}
\setlength{\labelsep}{3cm}


\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\sidesubfloat[]{\includegraphics[scale=0.25]{example-image-a}}
\\
\vspace{1cm}
\sidesubfloat[]{\includegraphics[scale=0.25]{example-image-b}}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks so much, this seems to do the trick :) Do you know why the `capbesidesep` parameter doesn't work?

Comment: @dontpanic With `capbesidesep` you can modify the distance between the caption of the whole figure and the image. It seems not to be used for labels of subfigures.

Comment: oh! I see! thanks for the clarification! :)

Comment: @dontpanic You're welcome!

Answer (score 1):

I have put into `\sidesubfloat[]` an horizontal space of 1 cm `\hspace{1cm}`.
Could it be a convenient solution for you? I hope I have answered your question.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{floatrow}

\newlength\mysep \setlength\mysep{1cm}
\DeclareFloatSeparators{mysep}{\hskip\mysep}
\floatsetup[figure]{style=plain,subcapbesideposition=top,capbesidesep=mysep}


\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\sidesubfloat[]{\hspace{1cm}\includegraphics[scale=0.25]{example-image-a}}
\\
\vspace{1cm}
\sidesubfloat[]{\includegraphics[scale=0.25]{example-image-b}}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Grazie mille, Sebastiano, ma cercavo qualcosa di più generico. Grazie cmq!

Comment: I admit with such sincerity that I am not as good as other users. You absolutely do not have to thank me. I was pleased to answer your question. The best of luck.